# Python Get Random Choice From Text File Then Repeat That Choice

Tags: python, html, random

This may seem rudimentary but I'm drawing a blank on how to accomplish this. It's basically for a href link and anchor text. I need to go get a random line from a text file, create the html code and then repeat the random choice I gathered as the anchor text. Here is my code thus far. How would I repeat my choice I got from the text file for my anchor text? Thank you for the help.

```
'<p><a href="/' + random.choice(list(open('data_files/script_only_files/titles.csv'))).replace(" ", "-").replace("---", "-").replace("\n", "").lower() + '/">' + random.choice(list(open('data_files/script_only_files/titles.csv'))).replace("\n", "") + '</a></p>'
```

This code works fine to get the url for the href but as you can see it also gets a random anchor text, which is not what I'm wanting to achieve. An example output I need to achieve would be like this:

```
<a href="/my-funny-wordpress-page/">My Funny Wordpress Page</a>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use a variable ?

```
mychoice = random.choice(list(open('data_files/script_only_files/titles.csv')))
mytag = '<p><a href="/' + mychoice.replace(" ", "-").replace("---", "-").replace("\n", "").lower() + '/">' + mychoice.replace("\n", "") + '</a></p>'
```